# MySQL select lowest timedate for each id

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event_showtime` (
  `id_show` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_event` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `event_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_show`),
  KEY `id_event` (`id_event`)
)
```

Values look like this, for example :

```
INSERT INTO `event_showtime` (`id_show`, `id_event`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `event_date_time`) VALUES
(1, 1, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-03-31 16:13:17'),
(2, 1, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-04-01 20:00:00'),
(3, 2, 49.2113914818564, 18.7520992416382, '2014-03-31 15:00:00'),
(4, 2, 49.0545135142313, 20.2952223676682, '2014-04-16 11:00:00'),
(5, 2, 49.2113914818564, 18.7520992416382, '2014-04-23 11:00:00'),
(6, 2, 49.0545135142313, 20.2952223676682, '2014-04-30 11:00:00'),
(7, 2, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-04-29 12:00:00'),
(8, 1, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-04-24 12:00:00');
```

I would like to SELECT result in such way :

For each id_event I want to select nearest date, that is also > NOW() so the result should look like :

```
`id_event` `event_date_time` 
1 , '2014-04-24 12:00:00' 
2 , '2014-04-16 11:00:00'
```

How to achive this ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id_event, min(event_date_time) as lowest_date
from event_showtime
where event_date_time > now()
group by id_event
```